# How to run these PowerShell commands from a bat file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Afternoon everyone,

I need to add the following powershell commands from inside a Batch script, what is the correct way to do that? Greatly appreciate any help or tip on how to do that.

```
Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsAppsMicrosoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbweAppxManifest.xml"

Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsAppsMicrosoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbweAppxManifest.xml

Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsAppsMicrosoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.29231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbweAppxManifest.xml

Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsAppsMicrosoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.29231.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbweAppxManifest.xml

Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsAppsMicrosoft.WindowsStore_12009.1001.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbweAppxManifest.xml

Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsAppsMicrosoft.WindowsStore_12009.1001.113.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbweAppxManifest.xml
```

Comment: To call PowerShell commands from `cmd.exe` (a batch file), you must call `powershell.exe`, PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (in PowerShell [Core] v6+, it is `pwsh.exe`)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to write PowerShell commands you can use

`powershell -command "command"` as an example:

```
powershell -command "Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "C\Program Files\WindowsAppsMicrosoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2_2.2.28604.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbweAppxManifest.xml""
```

This should allow you to run PowerShell commands within a .bat file.

Another way you could also do this would be to call different .ps1 files from within the .bat file itself:

`powershell -file C:\users\xxxxx\appxpackage.ps1`

edit: as pointed out by mklement0 embedded `"` chars. must be escaped as `\"` and adding if string interpolation isn't needed, single-quoting can be used.

Comment: Yes, but note that the _embedded_ `"` chars. must be escaped as `\"` (or, if string interpolation isn't needed, single-quoting can be used).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try and let you know!

Would any of you also know how to grant permissions to a folder and subfolders to ourselves from CMD?

Comment: You should look into ACLs however I'd also suggest putting that in a different question, if this helps please be sure to make as correct and vote up if you like